# bash - field separator space or newline

Tags: bash

I'd like loop over data from stdin. Something like that:

```
while read -r line; do
   blah blah blah
done
```

But I cannot predict if my input data are separated by space or newline. Any ideas how to do it? Not spawning new process highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a a command producing this output?

Comment: Please edit your Q to show the range of input you will try to process, any inputs that should cause an error and then what is your expected output from your sample input. Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My effort is similar to @tripleee's but does not suffer from the globbing issue, I'm using an array and quoting the expansion:

```
while read -r -a items
do
    for item in "${items[@]}"     # Quotes are important here
    do
        echo "$item"  # blah blah blah
    done
done < gash.txt
```

Note that it is important to use `"${items[@]}"`, *not* `"${items[*]}"`.

EDIT:  Re. comment above, to ignore tabs as separators:

```
while IFS=$'\n ' read -r -a items
```

Comment: Mine is actually POSIX compliant I think, but that's moot for a question tagged [tag:bash]. This gets my +1

Comment: @tripleee:  take your point about POSIX, I am honoured by the +1.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't particularly elegant or efficient, but it does meet the requirement of using only shell-internal functionality.

```
while read -r line; do
    for word in $line; do
        blah blah blah "$word"
    done
done
```

Using `$line` without quotes subjects the value not only to whitespace tokenization but also wildcard expansion; if you want to avoid that, [the `noglob` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) is your friend, though toggling it on and off in your script is a huge hassle if you need globbing to work in some other part -- maybe spending an external process is a smaller problem then.

Comment: note that it will also split on tabs `\t` but may be changed with IFS

Answer (score 0):

you could convert all spaces to newlines with tr:

```
tr ' ' '\n'
```

Comment: This does spawn one additional process, though.